# What is the sequence of pPROLar.A plasmid?

Tags: sequence-analysis, cloning, plasmids

I've been looking for the sequence of pPROLar.A122 plasmid but I haven't found it. Where could I find the sequence?

The first [link (addgene)](https://www.addgene.org/28013/) on googling reports a plasmid which is reported to have the pPROLar.A backbone. However, this is a modified version with Ampicillin and LuxR. I'm trying to reconstruct it from it and another plasmid.

The plasmid map looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is not. pPROLar.A122 plasmid looks like this: http://apps2.bvl.bund.de/vectorwww/image.do?id=427 and this is a modified version with Ampicillin and LuxR. But I'm trying to reconstruct it from it and another plasmid.

Comment: The problem is the reliability of reconstructed sequences. If a problem arrives with the cloning maybe was because of that. I've already searched the whole Google, that's the reason because I asked here.

Comment: I am afraid the sequence is not available anywhere. You should write to Clontech to ask for it. If you do get a reply then please post it here. It will be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pPROLar.A112 sequence is:

> CCATGGGTGA ACAGAAACTG ATCAGCGAAG AGGATCTGGG TGGAGATGAC GATGACAAGG
>   TGGTCGACAA GCTTGGATCC CTGCAGGCCT CAGGGCCCGA TCGATGCGGC CGCTTAATTA
>   ATTAATCTAG AGGCATCAAA TAAAACGAAA GGCTCAGTCG AAAGACTGGG CCTTTCGTTT
>   TATCTGTTGT TTGTCGGTGA ACGCTCTCCT GAGTAGGACA AATCCGCCGC CCTAGACCTA
>   GGGGATATAT TCCGCTTCCT CGCTCACTGA CTCGCTACGC TCGGTCGTTC GACTGCGGCG
>   AGCGGAAATG GCTTACGAAC GGGGCGGAGA TTTCCTGGAA GATGCCAGGA AGATACTTAA
>   CAGGGAAGTG AGAGGGCCGC GGCAAAGCCG TTTTTCCATA GGCTCCGCCC CCCTGACAAG
>   CATCACGAAA TCTGACGCTC AAATCAGTGG TGGCGAAACC CGACAGGACT ATAAAGATAC
>   CAGGCGTTTC CCCCTGGCGG CTCCCTCGTG CGCTCTCCTG TTCCTGCCTT TCGGTTTACC
>   GGTGTCATTC CGCTGTTATG GCCGCGTTTG TCTCATTCCA CGCCTGACAC TCAGTTCCGG
>   GTAGGCAGTT CGCTCCAAGC TGGACTGTAT GCACGAACCC CCCGTTCAGT CCGACCGCTG
>   CGCCTTATCC GGTAACTATC GTCTTGAGTC CAACCCGGAA AGACATGCAA AAGCACCACT
>   GGCAGCAGCC ACTGGTAATT GATTTAGAGG AGTTAGTCTT GAAGTCATGC GCCGGTTAAG
>   GCTAAACTGA AAGGACAAGT TTTGGTGACT GCGCTCCTCC AAGCCAGTTA CCTCGGTTCA
>   AAGAGTTGGT AGCTCAGAGA ACCTTCGAAA AACCGCCCTG CAAGGCGGTT TTTTCGTTTT
>   CAGAGCAAGA GATTACGCGC AGACCAAAAC GATCTCAAGA AGATCATCTT ATTAATCAGA
>   TAAAATATTA CTAGATTTCA GTGCAATTTA TCTCTTCAAA TGTAGCACCT GAAGTCAGCC
>   CCATACGATA TAAGTTGTTA CTAGTGCTTG GATTCTCACC AATAAAAAAC GCCCGGCGGC
>   AACCGAGCGT TCTGAACAAA TCCAGATGGA GTTCTGAGGT CATTACTGGA TCTATCAACA
>   GGAGTCCAAG CGAGCTCTCG AACCCCAGAG TCCCGCTCAG AAGAACTCGT CAAGAAGGCG
>   ATAGAAGGCG ATGCGCTGCG AATCGGGAGC GGCGATACCG TAAAGCACGA GGAAGCGGTC
>   AGCCCATTCG CCGCCAAGCT CTTCAGCAAT ATCACGGGTA GCCAACGCTA TGTCCTGATA
>   GCGGTCCGCC ACACCCAGCC GGCCACAGTC GATGAATCCA GAAAAGCGGC CATTTTCCAC
>   CATGATATTC GGCAAGCAGG CATCGCCATG GGTCACGACG AGATCCTCGC CGTCGGGCAT
>   GCGCGCCTTG AGCCTGGCGA ACAGTTCGGC TGGCGCGAGC CCCTGATGCT CTTCGTCCAG
>   ATCATCCTGA TCGACAAGAC CGGCTTCCAT CCGAGTACGT GCTCGCTCGA TGCGATGTTT
>   CGCTTGGTGG TCGAATGGGC AGGTAGCCGG ATCAAGCGTA TGCAGCCGCC GCATTGCATC
>   AGCCATGATG GATACTTTCT CGGCAGGAGC AAGGTGAGAT GACAGGAGAT CCTGCCCCGG
>   CACTTCGCCC AATAGCAGCC AGTCCCTTCC CGCTTCAGTG ACAACGTCGA GCACAGCTGC
>   GCAAGGAACG CCCGTCGTGG CCAGCCACGA TAGCCGCGCT GCCTCGTCCT GCAGTTCATT
>   CAGGGCACCG GACAGGTCGG TCTTGACAAA AAGAACCGGG CGCCCCTGCG CTGACAGCCG
>   GAACACGGCG GCATCAGAGC AGCCGATTGT CTGTTGTGCC CAGTCATAGC CGAATAGCCT
>   CTCCACCCAA GCGGCCGGAG AACCTGCGTG CAATCCATCT TGTTCAATCA TGCGAAACGA
>   TCCTCATCCT GTCTCTTGAT CAGATCTTGA TCCCCTGCGC CATCAGATCC TTGGCGGCAA
>   GAAAGCCATC CAGTTTACTT TGCAGGGCTT CCCAACCTTA CCAGAGGGCG CCCCAGCTGG
>   CAATTCCGAC GTCTGTGTGG AATTGTGAGC GGATAACAAT TTCACACAGG GCCCTCGGAC
>   ACCGAGGAGA ATGTCAAGAG GCGAACACAC AACGTCTTGG AGCGCCAGAG GAGGAACGAG
>   CTAAAACGGA GCTTTTTTGC CCTGCGTGAC CAGATCCCGG AGTTGGAAAA CAATGAAAAG
>   GCCCCCAAGG TAGTTATCCT TAAAAAAGCC ACAGCATACA TCCTGTCCGT CCAAGCAGAG
>   GAGCAAAAGC TCATTTCTGA AGAGGACTTG TTGCGGAAAC GACGAGAACA GTTGAAACAC
>   AAACTTGAAC AGCTACGGAA CTCTTGTGCG TAAGGAAAAG TAAGGAAAAC GATTCCTTCT
>   AACAGAAATG TCCTGAGCAA TCACCTATGA ACTGTCGACT CGAGCATAGC ATTTTTATCC
>   ATAAGATTAG CGGATCTAAC CTTTACAATT GTGAGCGCTC ACAATTATGA TAGATTCAAT
>   TGTGAGCGGA TAACAATTTC ACACAGAATT CATTAAAGAG GAGAAAGGTA C

It was sent to me directly from Takara Bio.